# Is there any parser for go:generate directives?

Tags: go

It seems the standard [doc](https://golang.org/src/go/doc/doc.go#L14) package is not parsing go:generate comments. Any idea how can I get those comments?

Comment: Looking at the [`go generate` source code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/generate.go), you can see that it simply checks if the line starts with `//go:generate ` or `//go:generate\t`.

Comment: Looks quite primitive to me. Now I guess I have to copy/paste a bunch of code from go generate source   b/c the functions are all private.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Package [`go/parser`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/parser/) in the standard library gets you an `ast.Package` value, representing an abstract syntax tree of a single package. This tree includes `ast.Comment` nodes, whose textual content you can easily access through their `Text` field.

Edit:

[Dewy Broto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4122236/dubroto) contributed: A more direct option is to call the go/scanner package with the ScanComments flag set to true. There's no need to build an AST to find the comments

Comment: A more direct option is to call the [go/scanner](http://godoc.org/go/scanner) package with the [ScanComments](http://godoc.org/go/scanner#ScanComments) flag set to true. There's no need to build an AST to find the comments.

Comment: The `Text` field also removes go:directives so the `ast/parser` package no longer works
https://pkg.go.dev/go/ast#CommentGroup.Text